# Is ARIMAX(0, 0, 0) OLS?

Tags: time-series, arima, least-squares

I have been fitting some models to a time series I have and amongst these are an AIRMAX(0, 0, 0) model. I am using the `statsmodels` implementation of ARIMA(X) in `python` and have a simple question:

> Is an ARIMAX(0, 0, 0) model simply an OLS model?

My interpretation of the sparse [documentation](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMA.html) is that it is. Can someone confirm this or explain why I am wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ARIMA**X**(0,0,0) is **a model**. OLS is **an estimation technique**. This is an apples-to-oranges comparison.

ARIMA(0,0,0) model for a dependent variable $y_t$ means $y_t=\beta_0+\varepsilon_t$ where $\beta_0$ is a constant and $\varepsilon_t$ is white noise. You do not even need OLS to estimate such a model, as there is not much to estimate. You can obtain  $\beta_0$ as the empirical mean of $y$ and the variance of $\varepsilon_t$ as the empirical variance of $y$.

ARIMA**X**(0,0,0) could be understood as $y_t=\beta_0+\beta_1 x_t+\varepsilon_t$. This model could be estimated by OLS. (Loosely speaking you *could* say this is an OLS model, and many people would understand what you intend to express. Yet I suggest keeping a distinction between models and estimation techniques; this may come in handy in some more complicated situations when clear terminology may prevent larger confusion.)

Comment: Thank you, very good, helpful, concise response. The distinction is, I believe, clear to me now.

Comment: @IvarEriksson, you are welcome!